# Parameterized types in OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml, parameterized

I try to use parameterized types in OCaml but it doesnt't work :(

In a first file "tree.ml" I define the type :

```
type 'a tree =
  | Node of ('a tree)*('a tree) 
  | Leaf of 'a
```

In another file "intTree.ml", I use this type to define a type t :

```
open Tree
type t = int tree
```

Finally, I want to use the type t in a function "size" in "main.ml" :

```
open IntTree

type r = IntTree.t

let rec size tree = match tree with
  | Leaf k -> 0
  | Node (t1,t2) -> 1 + size t1 + size t2
```

When I try to compile these files, I obtain the following error :

```
File "main.ml", line 6, characters 4-8:
Error: Unbound constructor Leaf
```

If i defined "main.mli", it doesn't change anything :

```
type r

val size : r -> int
```

If I put :

```
let rec size (tree : r) = match tree with
  | Leaf k -> 0
  | Node (t1,t2) -> 1 + size t1 + size t2
```

i have :

```
Warning 40: Leaf was selected from type Tree.tree.
It is not visible in the current scope, and will not 
be selected if the type becomes unknown.
...
```

I know they are solutions to solve this error quickly (for example, putting "open Tree type t = int tree" in main.ml instead of "open IntTree type t = IntTree.t") but I need to use the previous structure (for other reasons...). Is there a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Your `main.ml` opens `IntTree`, so it gets all the names defined there. However, `Leaf` isn't defined there; it's defined in `Tree`. So, as Kadaku says, you should open `Tree` in your `main.ml`. It seems like a lot of hassle, but that's because your modules are so tiny. In a real project you would have more names to control.

Comment: Also, instead of opening, I've personally found it more helpful in a large project to use the fully qualified name, `Tree.Leaf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `open Tree` in main.ml. You don't need to copy and paste type declaration. In you code compiler tries to guess what is on your mind. That's why adding type annotation manually partially solves the problem.

Compiler sees that you expect `tree` to be of type `r`, it looks at type `r` from module `IntTree` (which is opened by you) and there it understands that probably we have this constructors in `Tree` module. It opens it  with a warning. This feature was introduced rather recently, so don't be suprized that you are not aware of it.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to change this:

```
open Tree
```

to this:

```
include Tree
```

in `intTree.ml`. The idea is that `intTree` then becomes self-contained by including all the definitions from `Tree`.

Answer (score 0):

While adding `open Tree` in "main.ml" will solve the problem, it might be preferable to write the following to avoid polluting "main.ml" with eventual irrelevant definitions from "Tree.mli":

```
let rec size tree = match tree with
  | Tree.Leaf k -> 0
  | Tree.Node (t1,t2) -> 1 + size t1 + size t2
```